# How to add new List<t> to another List in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am just adding items to a list but can't get it to work. It keeps throwing errors expected ;, expected ).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Employee
{
    private int _id;
    private string _FName;
    private string _MName;
    private string _LName;
    private DateTime _DOB;
    private char _sex;

public int ID { get { return _id; } set { _id=value; } }
public string FName{get{return _FName;}set{_FName=value;}}
public string MName { get { return _MName; } set { _MName = value; } }
public string LName { get { return _LName; } set { _LName = value; } }
public DateTime DOB { get { return _DOB; } set { _DOB = value; } }
public char Sex { get { return _sex; } set { _sex = value; } }

public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
{
    List<Employee> empList=new List<Employee>();
    empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, FName = "John", MName = "", LName = "Shields", DOB = DateTime.Parse("12/11/1971"), Sex = 'M' });
    empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 2, FName = "Mary", MName = "Matthew", LName = "Jacobs", DOB = DateTime.Parse("01/17/1961"), Sex = 'F' });
    empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 3, FName = "Amber", MName = "Carl", LName = "Agar", DOB = DateTime.Parse("12/23/1971"), Sex = 'M' });
    empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 4, FName = "Kathy", MName = "", LName = "Berry", DOB = DateTime.Parse("11/15/1976"), Sex = 'F' });
    return empList;
}
}
```

Comment: You're targeting the .net2 runtime, but what C# compiler (or version of Visual Studio) are you using?

Comment: Hiya, I am using VSS 2005 perhaps its 2.0

Comment: Do you mean VS2005? VSS is the repo...

Comment: Sorry my bad, yep I meant VS2005 :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET 2, it's possibly using the C# 2 compiler (as per your title, actually) - which doesn't support the object initializer syntax you're using. If possible, try to upgrade to use the C# 3 compiler - or create an `Employee` constructor taking all of the relevant parameters.

So an expression like this:

```
new Employee() { ID = 1, FName = "John", MName = "", LName = "Shields", 
                 DOB = DateTime.Parse("12/11/1971"), Sex = 'M' }
```

would become

```
new Employee(1, "John", "", "Shields", "DOB", 'M')
```

Note that if you *were* using the C# 3 compiler, you wouldn't have to have all those manual calls to `Add`... you could just write:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee(... stuff here...),
    new Employee(... stuff here...)
};
```

You could still use object initializer syntax if you wanted, but the collection initializer syntax makes it simpler whatever approach you take to constructing `Employee` objects.

Comment: Thanks Jon. You are right about me using object initialization. I corrected the code like empList.Add(new Employee (1,  "John",  "", "Shields", DateTime.Parse("12/11/1971"), 'M' )); . Now it says No overload for method Employee takes 6 arguments on 'new'.

Comment: @Popo: Ahh... Add a constructor in your Employee class which accepts 6 arguments in the same order. That's what Jon said in his answer above as well.

Comment: Hey I am passing the arguments in right order. Do I have to initialize each object before adding it to my list ?

Comment: @Popo: Initialization is done by constructor. Have you added a 6-argument constructor in your class? I don't see it in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles just fine for me. Are you running a version of C# that supports object initializers (v. 3.0+)?

Here is the full code sample using a constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Employee
{
    private int _id;
    private string _FName;
    private string _MName;
    private string _LName;
    private DateTime _DOB;
    private char _sex;

    public int ID { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public string FName { get { return _FName; } set { _FName = value; } }
    public string MName { get { return _MName; } set { _MName = value; } }
    public string LName { get { return _LName; } set { _LName = value; } }
    public DateTime DOB { get { return _DOB; } set { _DOB = value; } }
    public char Sex { get { return _sex; } set { _sex = value; } }

    public Employee(int id, string fname, string mname, string lname, DateTime dob, char sex)
    {
        ID = id;
        FName = fname;
        MName = mname;
        LName = lname;
        DOB = dob;
        Sex = sex;
    }

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        empList.Add(new Employee(1, "John", "", "Shields", DateTime.Parse("12/11/1971"), 'M'));
        //etc
        return empList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, I am using VSS 2005.

Comment: That means you're using C# 2.0 :-) Check out Jon's answer on how to use constructors instead of object initializers.

Comment: Hey Jonas, I ran into a problem.

Comment: Updated my answer with a full solution that should be C# 2.0 compatible.